# How would I find the volume of a paraboloid, using volumes of revolution, with only the equation of the paraboloid?

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

I have been given an equation describing the surface of an open paraboloid, z = a^2 - x^2 - y^2. In this case, z is the 'vertical' axis, and a is some constant. z is also greater than or equal to 0.

I was asked to calculate the volume of the paraboloid using a volume integral and have done so. When this was done, the paraboloid was closed by a 'disk' at z=0. However, considering that paraboloids are solids of revolution, I was wondering if I could represent the paraboloid in a way that allows me to find its volume, using the volume of revolution formulae.

I was thinking I could find the equation describing the paraboloid if the x or y coordinate was fixed and proceed from there, but I'm having trouble finding this equation. Any help or other advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about iterated triple integrals? You could also think about this paraboloid as the surface generated by revolving $z=a^2-x^2,|x|\leq a$ around the $z-$ axis

Comment: This one is not a solid of revolution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by iterated triple integrals. I did use a triple integral with an appropriate parameterization to find the volume originally. This was how the particular question wanted me to do it. Thanks for the advice about the surface rotation, I'll try that now.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, the surface method worked well, and was a lot quicker than the method in the question.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about closing with a disk at $z = 0$. Whether you close with a lid or not, that does not change the volume. Secondly, the volume of revolution is simply volume of revolution of a parabola in $YZ$ plane or in $XZ$ plane, around $z$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this yesterday using Matthew Pilling's method. It was much quicker than doing the original method.

The answer was Pi*a^4 all divided by 2.